# WordPress published posts and revisions + custom post types

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, revisions

I stumbled up on one problem with revisions that I have to use for on website im building in wordpress.

So, it goes something like this. I installed Capability Manager plugin so I was able to make a new role account and set the permissions for that role. After that I installed Revisionary. What I basically did is that I copied Contributor role and removed some things. So new account now can edit only their own post. When the post is edited revisionary (the plugin) enables only "send to a revision" option, so the user cant publish it. The thing is even if the post is new or was already published, every change needs a revision and I managed to do that. After that I installed the plugin called "Manage your posts only". I need that one so a new user who can add new posts is unable to see other posts that he is not author of.

BUT I have a small problem. The revisionary plugin doesnt work with custom post types, fields etc. (Woothemes theme in this particular situation). So only thing that can be changed is a post text and title, everything else below the post, custom fields and so on are ignored by revisionary. I need your help guys and your opinions what would be the best solution for this problem.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question - might be better suited to the Webmasters site.

Answer (score 0):

i did a little searching around and found this - it seems the original plugin hasn't developed support for custom post types but this exta plugin adds that support

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-revisions/